# Error with Function implementing CASE statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 different functions for one group, 2 of these functions work fine but for some reason, I keep getting an error on the 3rd function (ClosedEnrollment) where it won't generate the date. I'm not really too sure as to why, I have attached a picture of my Excel worksheet.

[Image Error for Closed Enrollment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F76xA.png)
[Image of VBA Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQCaJ.png)

```
Function GracePeriod(grp, status, DOH)
Application.Volatile True
                
     Select Case grp
        Case "Group 1"
            Select Case status
                Case "Upper MGMT", "UPPER MANAGEMENT", "REG FT-Div 10", "REG FT-Div 9", "Reg PT-Div 10", "Reg PT-Div 9", "Regular FT-Division 10", "Upper Management", "Regular PT - Division 10": GracePeriod = (DOH) + 30
                    End Select
                End Select
  
End Function
Function ClosedEnrollment(opEnrl)
Application.Volatile True
Dim orEnrl As String

    Select Case opEnrl
        Case "Group 1":
            ClosedEnrollment = (opEnrl) + 20
        End Select
    
End Function
Function OpenEnrollment(grp, status, DOH)
Application.Volatile True

    Select Case grp
   
        Case "Group 1"
             If Day(DOH + 60) = 1 Then
                OpenEnrollment = DOH + 60
                    Else
                        OpenEnrollment = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(DOH + 60, 0) + 1 - (30)
                    End If
                End Select
                
End Function
```

Comment: Looking at your Screenshots and Arguments (which lack Type Declarations…), I find myself confused: by "the 3rd function", do you mean `OpenEnrollment` (the third function in the code), or `ClosedEnrollmen`t (the third function in the execution-order for the spreadsheet)? If the latter, look much more carefully at the arguments you are supplying, and you'll see that it cannot simultaneously be a Date and a String of "Group 1" (Meaning you always get a result of either 0, for a Date-input, or `#VALUE!`, for a String-input)

Comment: Hello, @Chronocidal I'm getting the error in the ClosedEnrollment Function, prior to adding the string I was still getting the error. Essentially, it will always be ClosedEnrollment = OpenEnrollment + 20. So I just have a function to add the results of the OpenEnrollment case results onto the "Open Enrollment" column, but I keep getting the error date.

Comment: The point is that you cannot add 20 to the string "Group 1" - it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: If the `ClosedEnrollment` is always  `ClosedEnrollment = OpenEnrollment + 20` couldn't you just use a regular formula in Column G? Like `=E2+20`

Comment: ahhh I see what you mean, thank you for your input.

Comment: `Application.Volatile True` is likely both unnecessary and a bad idea here.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have clarified which function is giving the error…  Let's break it down line by line:

```
Function ClosedEnrollment(opEnrl)
    Application.Volatile True
    Dim orEnrl As String

    Select Case opEnrl
        Case "Group 1":
            ClosedEnrollment = (opEnrl) + 20
    End Select
End Function
```

So, your Argument seems to imply that `opEnrl` is the Enrollment date.  As such, let us first examine the scenario of `=ClosedEnrollment(Date(2023,8,2))`

- `Application.Volatile True` can be ignored, as this just marks the Function as Volatile
- `Dim orEnrl As String` This line does nothing, because `orEnrl` is never used. Ignore it too
- `Select Case opEnrl` - well, `opEnrl` is a Date, 2nd August 2023…
- `Case "Group 1":` … but the only Case we examine is when `opEnrl` is a *String*, "Group 1"
- `ClosedEnrollment = (opEnrl) + 20` Ignore this line, because `OpEnrl` does **not** equal `"Group 1"`
- `End Select` - and there are no more cases.

End result: you never set the value of `ClosedEnrollment`, so it defaults to `0`.

Now, your *usage* implies that `opEnrl` is the GroupCase.  As such, let us
next examine the scenario of `=ClosedEnrollment("Group 1")`:

- `Application.Volatile True` can be ignored, as this just marks the Function as Volatile
- `Dim orEnrl As String` This line does nothing, because `orEnrl` is never used. Ignore it too
- `Select Case opEnrl` - well, `opEnrl` is a String, `"Group 1"`…
- `Case "Group 1":` … which means that this is the Case we run
- `ClosedEnrollment = (opEnrl) + 20` This is `ClosedEnrollment = ("Group 1") + 20`, which will give a Type-mismatch error
- `End Select` - and there are no more cases

End result: your function returns a `#Value!` Error, because you tried to Add a String and a Number.

The **first** thing you need to do, is work out what this function *should* be doing.  Because, at the moment, it is rather a horrendous mismash.  And stuff like "throwing a random String declaration in", or "putting a variable in brackets" implies that you have tried to paper-over error messages that cropped up, *without* considering what those messages were saying.

I would, *very naïvely*, assume that you might need to add a second Argument, with the Group (my assumption being that different Groups might have different Enrollment periods, so you can't just Add 20 to the date). so, **maybe** something like this:

```
Function ClosedEnrollment(grp AS String, opEnrl AS Date) AS Date
    Application.Volatile True

    Select Case grp
        Case "Group 1":
            ClosedEnrollment = opEnrl + 20
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. This worked as well!!! I appreciate your input. I'll work more on identifying what the errors mean coming forward.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Function ClosedEnrollment(opEnrl)
Application.Volatile True

    ClosedEnrollment = (opEnrl) + 20
    
End Function
```

You don't need the Select Case, because it's already been handled in the OpenEnrollment function.